# Splitting of an RGB image to R G B using OpenCv Python

Tags: python, opencv

When i am splitting my image I am not getting the frames in colors of Red,Green,Blue. The frames I got in output are three Gray color images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Pavan\\Desktop\\bird.jpg")
#display an image
cv2.imshow('image',img)
b,g,r=cv2.split(img)
cv2.imshow('b',b)
cv2.imshow('g',g)
cv2.imshow('r',r)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: that's the expected output. to see the color you need an RGB image with 3 colors, a single color becomes grayscale simply because nobody knows what color that is.

Comment: That is correct and normal. You have changed your 3-channel image into 3 distinct, single channel images. A single channel image does not contain colour, it is a greyscale image.

Comment: If you want it blue, make an empty channel with `empty=np.zeroslike(b)` and then merge your blue with 2 empty channels `result=cv2.merge((b,empty,empty))`

Answer (score 6):

Here are two ways to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy.

```
Method 1 is to copy the image 3 times and set the appropriate other channels to black

Method 2 is to split the image merge each with a black image for the other channels (suggested in comments by Mark Setchell)
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('mandril3.jpg')

# Method 1: copy image and set other channels to black
r = img.copy()
r[:,:,0] = r[:,:,1] = 0

g = img.copy()
g[:,:,0] = g[:,:,2] = 0

b = img.copy()
b[:,:,1] = b[:,:,2] = 0

cv2.imshow("red",r)
cv2.imshow("green",g)
cv2.imshow("blue",b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# Method 2: split channels and merge with black channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
k = np.zeros_like(b)
b = cv2.merge([b,k,k])
g = cv2.merge([k,g,k])
r = cv2.merge([k,k,r])

cv2.imshow("red",r)
cv2.imshow("green",g)
cv2.imshow("blue",b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite("mandril3_red.jpg", r)
cv2.imwrite("mandril3_green.jpg", g)
cv2.imwrite("mandril3_blue.jpg", b)
```

Red:

[image]

Green:

[image]

Blue:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Try writing your output and calling that particular variable as the example given;

`Blue = cv2.imwrite('blue_channel.jpg', b)`

`cv2.imshow('Blue Channel, Blue)`

Comment: `cv2.imwrite` returns `True / False` -- that's not the type of an argument you'd like to pass to `cv2.imshow()`

Comment: How do you *"call a variable"*? Surely you only *"call"* functions and when using variables you either *"set"* them or *"access"* their contents.